# How to give user an options to save file in there desired location in C#?

Tags: c#, file, console-application

I know how to create and save a file in C# console application but what if i want the user to choose the location of where they want to save it? i have no idea on how i can make this possible.

edit- ive realised that would be very hard to input the location the user wants to save the file to however is it possible to save the file as you would do when creating a windows word document, so the user would be able to see where they want to save the file [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kb6ND.jpg)

Comment: I believe (and the answer by Taumantis seems to confirm) you can still popup a file dialog box from a console application.  If you truly wanted to go full retro and make your application text only, there's the ever popular prompt the user for the file path route

Comment: So you have o be more specific

Comment: Typically, the full console route involves not asking the user for the save location, but requiring it to be specified on the command line. This has advantages, in that the terminal/command window can be used to get at paths, including using the Tab key to autocomplete, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a full console application, that is no windows being created, then there's only *one proper thing* to do: require the user to specify the save location on the command line.*

Given the fact that you have a console application, you probably already do some checking of the command line, but if not, then the command line can be read from the `args` argument to your `Program.Main`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ...
}
```

There are examples on the internet to handle the command line, if you get stuck, or a new question can be asked specifically for the issue you are having.

---

*) Now, for the reason why this is the only proper way:

If the user needs to pass it on the command line, then the user has all the usual niceties such as tab completion available. The user can also use `dir` and `cd` before calling your program to find the proper directory.

On the other hand, if you ask the user to input it, then the user will *not* have tab completion, will *not* be able to use `dir` or `cd`, and as such will have to type it out manually all the way. Typo's or mistakes are almost guaranteed.

From a user experience point of view, this is very annoying. Programmers should therefore *not* ask the user to manually type out file paths during program execution. Hence, it must be specified on the command line.

Comment: how about instead of typing our the location they want to save the file to, they instead save it as you would do if you where to make a windows word document, is that possible?

Comment: @AshrafRahman Yes, see the answers by mrsargent and Taumantis. Here, a selection dialog (the default windows one) will be displayed and the user can select.

Answer (score 0):

Read about [SaveFileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.aspx)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
     Stream myStream ;
     SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();

     saveFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"  ;
     saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2 ;
     saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true ;

     if(saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
     {
         if((myStream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
         {
             // Code to write the stream goes here.
             myStream.Close();
         }
     }
}
```

And ready to test example from msdn [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfezx97z(VS.85).aspx)

if you want to play with something like >cd (ChDir) then look at

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory
```

or/and force user to write good directory by himselft and use @Carl aswere :) but remember we leave in 21 century people are lazy

Comment: OP is using a console app , don't think dialog's are what he wants

Comment: I think he wants OOTB microsft showdialog, but if not then implementation of something like "cd" is good option too I totally agree

Answer (score 0):

It is not hard. You need a console to read user's input with `string path = Console.ReadLine();`. User will input prefered path and it will store into `path` variable. Now you should check if this path exits `if(Directory.Exists(path))` it will return true if path exists false if path does not exist.

Code example:

```
Console.WriteLine("Insert a path: ");
string path = Console.ReadLine();

if(Directory.Exists(path)){
//save logic
}
else{
//path does not exist handler
}
```

Note: if you want to access Directory class you should use `System.IO` namespace.

Comment: This would require me to type the full path on the command line, without any tab completion or tools. It's really a last-ditch effort, and very annoying from a user-experience standpoint.

Comment: @MicroVirus He is using console application. You cannot do much to solve the problem. You can store all available paths into array/list and then display them and assign ID next to it and expect user to input Index instead of full path. Anyway you will not avoid redundancy in this case anyway. Anyway, that is what OP asked and I have provided the answer to his question. Please do let me know on how to improve so I can make it better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SaveFileDialog as Taumantis said but you have to add the

> System.Windows.Froms

namespace and you must mark your main method as a single apartment thread

```
 class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
  SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();

        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
        saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {

        }


        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```